# Sort a calculated column SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

I am looking for a way to sort a calculated column in my SSAS Tabular Model. I tried using the property **Sort by column** but apparently it is not working. Is it in general possible to do this?

In my case specific use case, I made a parent-child hierarchy where I want to sort on another column. Despite trying a lot of possibilities, it doesn't work. But neither does sorting a calculated column.

Note: Working with tabular compatibility 1400 (SQL2017).

Comment: What do you need this sorting for?

Comment: In Excel, we're importing data from Analysis Services. So we're using the Tabular Model. We need the data in a specific order which is not asc or desc

Answer (score 1):

**Sort by column** does work. The column to be sorted and the "Sort by column" must match values one for one, i.e. both columns need to be at the same level of granularity. In general, this is done on dimension tables, not fact tables.

The classic example for this feature is for sorting month labels. To change the sorting of MonthName from April, August, December... to January, February, March..., you need to sort MonthName by MonthNumber. Select the column to be sorted and set the Sort by column to a numeric column in the same table with the correct sort order. You would do this in the Date dimension, not in the Fact table with all the data.

Here's before and after pictures to prove it works:
[image: Before and after Sort by column]